# Heroku Docker failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose, dockerfile, dockerhub

Hello I Have Hosted A Dockerfile On Heroku But I Am Getting Error Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch.

Here Is The Link Of The Github [Repo](https://github.com/kenil261615/sabnzbdfinal/)

I Have Tried All The Available Solutions Of This Error. But Didn't Worked Any Of Them.